# Apache client http/1.1 406 not acceptable Java

Tags: java, api, jakarta-ee, apache-commons-httpclient

I tried to use the put method with the apache client. Get method is working fine but don't know put is not working.

The output of my below code: HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable

```
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPut put = new HttpPut("https://securecod3.myshopify.com");

        try {
            HashMap<String,HashMap> myMap = new HashMap<>();
            HashMap<String,String> value = new HashMap<>();
            value.put("value","<img src='Javacode.png'><p>We are busy updating the store for you and will be back within the hour.</p>");
            value.put("key","templates/index.liquid");
            myMap.put("asset",value);
            Helper hp = new Helper();
            hp.convertJson(myMap);
            System.out.println(hp.convertJson(myMap).toString());


            StringEntity se =   new StringEntity(hp.convertJson(myMap).toString(),"UTF8");
            put.setEntity(se);
            put.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
            put.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
            System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
            List<Header> httpHeaders = Arrays.asList(response.getAllHeaders());
                    System.out.println(httpHeaders);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You're setting the "Accept" request header value to "application/json"; did you mean to set the "Content-Type" instead?

Comment: Yes, I changed it but still not working

Comment: Does "still not working" mean you're still getting "406 Not Acceptable" even though you're not setting the `Accept` header? You're sure you're running the updated code?

Comment: I don't know anything about the API, but are you certain that's the correct URL? What reference did you follow that describes how to do this?

Comment: Ohh it is working now. i put setHeader twice.
One more question 
With this code i get only status code
How do i get body content
Like in php i used to do this 
'headers' => $headers, 'original_response' => $response, 'response' => $response[1], 'status' => "0"

Comment: Can you share your updated code. What do you mean by setHeader twice ? I am still facing the same issue in HttpPost.